# How to disable chef-client run

Tags: chef-infra

I want to disable chef-client run instead of stopping chef-client service or removing cron job schedule which means chef-client will never run again unless run manually.

Coming from puppet background, I am looking for an alternative like "puppet agent --disable" which will keep the chef-client service/cron running but it will not alter any resource.

It is more likely forcing every chef-client run into --why-run mode. Very useful while during upgrades or application deployment. It will allow to make revision/version change in chef role/recipe and apply in set of nodes, otherwise chef-client service or cron has to stop/disable first and re-enabled later which is not a right approach.

I do not see any such option in chef-client binary.

Chef Server and Client version - 11.8.2.

-thanks

Answer (score 4):

> which is not a right approach.

Why would you say that? Stopping and starting a service was designed exactly for these kind of situations. Simply use (depending on your preferred way of managing services) `service stop chef-client` and then run `service start chef-client` again once you are ready to resume operations.

We use this very regularly, when we want to mess with some configurations on a server before applying them to the Chef scripts. This makes sure Chef doesn't run during our messing around and reverts our manual changes.

Comment: Starting service will execute a chef run and any manual change will be reverted and new changes introduced to Chef will be applied.  
 I am simply trying to put chef-client service or chef-client manual run in noop or --why-run mode so that i do not have to stop/start the services every time i am deploying new code to a group of nodes.  
 This way i can simply tell chef-client not to perform any action, but keep running. Puppet has --disable mode which does exactly the same thing, it also prevented high load on puppet server when nodes starts at same time.

Comment: I still don't quite follow the use-case you are after. If you don't want manual changes to be reverted, then why start chef-client at that point anyway? As for `--why-run` mode, and "high load on server when nodes start at the same time", I suggest you look into both the `--why-run` and `--splay` flags which solve exactly these situations you described.

Comment: One instance where `--disable` is useful is when multiple people administer the machine. You can't accidentally re-enable service and you can differentiate between "the service never started/failed" and "some human deliberately disabled the service".

Comment: Isn't it service chef-client stop and service chef-client start ?  I think the answer's stop and start should not be in the middle but at the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo systemctl stop chef-client
```

worked for me on RHEL 7.5 64-bit

Answer (score 0):

```
/etc/init.d/chef-client stop
```

worked for me on CentOS release 6.6 (Final) running 2.6.32-504.16.2.el6.x86_64 kernel

Answer (score 0):

Reasons for wanting something like this -- and I'm thinking of Puppet too -- include:

- Wanting to test something on a system for an extended time without Chef clobbering it.  Lab / virtual test systems don't always suffice.
- Not having to trouble 24/7 staff with an alert because I stopped the service on a specific system

Looking for some semaphore file in /var/chef would be trivial to implement.